# Find subgroups of a numpy array

Tags: numpy

I have a numpy array like this one:

```
A = ([249,    250,   3016,   3017,   5679,   5680,   8257,   8258,
    10756,  10757,  13178,  13179,  15531,  15532,  17824,  17825,
    20058,  20059,  22239,  22240,  24373,  24374,  26455,  26456,
    28491,  28492,  30493,  30494,  32452,  32453,  34377,  34378,
    36264,  36265,  38118,  38119,  39939,  39940,  41736,  41737,
    43501,  43502,  45237,  45238,  46950,  46951,  48637,  48638])
```

I would like to write a small script that finds a subgroup of values of the array for which the difference is smaller than a certain threshold, let say 3, and that returns the highest value of the subgroup. In the case of A array the output should be:

```
A_out =([250,3017,5680,8258,10757,13179,...])
```

Is there a numpy function for that?

Comment: The values in your example are strictly increasing.  Is that always the case?

Comment: Yes, it is always the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a vectorized Numpy approach.

First, the data (in a numpy array) and the threshold:

```
In [41]: A = np.array([249,    250,   3016,   3017,   5679,   5680,   8257,   8258,
    10756,  10757,  13178,  13179,  15531,  15532,  17824,  17825,
    20058,  20059,  22239,  22240,  24373,  24374,  26455,  26456,
    28491,  28492,  30493,  30494,  32452,  32453,  34377,  34378,
    36264,  36265,  38118,  38119,  39939,  39940,  41736,  41737,
    43501,  43502,  45237,  45238,  46950,  46951,  48637,  48638])

In [42]: threshold = 3
```

The following produces the array `delta`.  It is almost the same as `delta = np.diff(A)`, but I want to include one more value that is greater than the threshold at the end of `delta`.

```
In [43]: delta = np.hstack((diff(A), threshold + 1))
```

Now the group maxima are simply `A[delta > threshold]`:

```
In [46]: A[delta > threshold]
Out[46]: 
array([  250,  3017,  5680,  8258, 10757, 13179, 15532, 17825, 20059,
       22240, 24374, 26456, 28492, 30494, 32453, 34378, 36265, 38119,
       39940, 41737, 43502, 45238, 46951, 48638])
```

Or, if you want, `A[delta >= threshold]`.  That gives the same result for this example:

```
In [47]: A[delta >= threshold]
Out[47]: 
array([  250,  3017,  5680,  8258, 10757, 13179, 15532, 17825, 20059,
       22240, 24374, 26456, 28492, 30494, 32453, 34378, 36265, 38119,
       39940, 41737, 43502, 45238, 46951, 48638])
```

There is a case where this answer differs from @DrV's answer.  From your description, it isn't clear to me how a set of values such as `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6` should be handled.  The consecutive differences are all 1, but the difference between the first and last is 5.  The numpy calculation above will treat these as a single group.  @DrV's answer will create two groups.

Comment: If you wanted the rightmost value of a 'linked cluster', you could extend this solution as linked = delta > threshold, A[diff(linked)==-1]

Answer (score -1):

**Interpretation 1: The value of an item in a group must not differ more than 3 units from that of the first item of the group**

This is one of the things where NumPy's capabilities are at their limits. As you will have to iterate through the list, I suggest a pure Python approach:

```
first_of_group = A[0]
previous = A[0]
group_lasts = []
for a in A[1:]:
    # if this item no longer belongs to the group
    if abs(a - first_of_group) > 3:
        group_lasts.append(previous)
        first_of_group = a
    previous = a
# add the last item separately, because it is always a last of the group
group_lasts.append(a)
```

Now you have the group lasts in `group_lasts`.

Using any NumPy array functionality here does not seem to provide much help.

**Interpretation 2: The value of an item in a group must not differ more than 3 units from the previous item**

This is easier, as we can easily form a list of group breaks as in `Warren Weckesser`'s answer. Here NumPy is of a lot of help.